# How to add username field in request header on IIS server with windows authentication

Tags: iis, http-headers, windows-authentication, reverse-proxy, url-rewrite-module

I have an web application that runs on 4502 port and I use IIS server with url rewrite module so it works like reverse proxy with windows authorisation. It works fine but I can't get username field on my application. Is it possible to add username field on IIS server when request come? Thank you.